# Unrecognized option when running Java via systemd

Tags: java, service, systemd

I am trying to run a Java application as a system service with systemd. The `.service` file for the service has the following command line:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -cp $CLASSPATH:/path/to/my.jar org.example.MainClass -myoption
```

where `-myoption` is an option intended to be passed to the `main()` method of the main class.

The command line works as expected when I launch it from bash; the option is passed to the main class.

However, when I try to start the service with `systemctl start` and then query its status with `systemctl status`, I see that the JVM terminated with:

```
Unrecognized option: -myoption
```

Apparently, the JVM is trying to make some sense of `-myoption` instead of passing it to the main class as an argument.

As the service is designed to exit upon the JVM being sent a `SIGINT`, I cannot use workarounds which will obscure the PID of the JVM from systemd.

How can I pass a command line option to the main class when launching it as a systemd service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables in `ExecStart` must be enclosed in braces unless they are separate words (and cannot be used in the path to the executable itself).

The following works as expected:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -cp ${CLASSPATH}:/path/to/my.jar org.example.MainClass -myoption
```